# How to replace or remove the clock time?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a web crawler and I'm trying to remove the clock time from the DateTime. for example from the crawler I got "29 January 2019 09:46:46", how to remove or replace the "9:46:46" so that only "29 January 2019" left.

I have tried to write this code but it results in nothing. I use ".replace(time, ' ')" to remove the hours, minute, and second. But it looks like remove all the DateTime.

date_time = record.find('i').replace(time, ' ')

from the date_time I got dates based on the date on the website that I crawled. But I hope to get only the date, months, and year without the hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
import re
text = "29 january 2019 09:46:46"
justDate = re.split('\s\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}', text)[0]
```

Output:

```
justDate
Out[60]: '29 january 2019'
```

**Edit:**

OP also asked how to get just the time part of the string. To do so:

```
justTime =  re.split('\d{4}\s', text)[1]
```

Output:

```
justTime
Out[61]: '09:46:46'
```

Comment: it works thank you, but how about if I only want the time?

Comment: Then you can do: re.split('\d{4}\s', text)[1] <- this will give you '09:46:46'.

Comment: I see, I dont know that features before